MapServer - only one icon pr grid cell
How do I build a WMS that uses Vector Fields to render arrows, based on the values in two separate raster layers?
I'm following the example provided in the MapServer documentation:
https://mapserver.org/input/vector/vector_field.html
This works fine, but I'm only interested in one arrow pr. grid-cell. When zooming in on a specific grid-cell, MapServer renders multiple identical arrows.
